# Есть инлайн кнопки "лайк", "дизлайк" Телеграм бот. Как изменить значение кнопки после нажатия на неё?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Решил засунуть переменные quant1 и quant2 в строки кнопок. Но как их изменить по нажатию на кнопку не знаю. Смастерил вот такой код. Но по нажатию вылезает ошибка:

**File "bottwo.py", line 86, in callback_vote_action
quant1 += 1
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple**

Вроде понятно что с числами в строке он работать не хочет, но как тогда сделать так чтобы он работал?\

```
vote_cb = CallbackData('vote', 'action')  # vote:<action>
likes = {}  # user_id: amount_of_likes



def get_keyboard():
    quant1 = 0
    quant2 = 0

    butlike = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' ' + str(quant1), callback_data=vote_cb.new(action='up'))
    butdilike = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' ' + str(quant2), callback_data=vote_cb.new(action='down'))

    return types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(butlike, butdilike)


@dp.callback_query_handler(vote_cb.filter(action=['up', 'down']))
async def callback_vote_action(query: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    logging.info('Получил данные обратного вызова: %r', callback_data)  # callback_data содержит всю информацию из данных обратного вызова
    await query.answer()  # Не забудьте ответить на запрос обратного вызова как можно скорее
    callback_data_action = callback_data['action']
    likes_count = likes.get(query.from_user.id, 0)


    if callback_data_action == 'up':
        likes_count += 1
        for quant1 in get_keyboard():
            quant1 += 1

        if likes_count == 1:
            pass
    else:
        likes_count -= 1
        for quant2 in get_keyboard():
            quant2 += 1

        if likes_count == 0:
            pass


    likes[query.from_user.id] = likes_count  # обновление количества лайков в хранилище
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Для работы с emoji удобно использовать пакет [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/)
2. В Python >= 3.6 появился [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), это более эффективный способ работы со строками
3. Посмотрите на этот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904547/1614174), кажется, что там приведено решение вашей задачи